# mirroring values of meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a mesh grid of 100x100 at (X & Y)
with values of fxn z at each grid.
Assume my grid on the x-axis starts and ends at  (0, 200) and on the y-axis it starts and ends at (0, 200).
Each grid stores a value of fxn Z.

If I have to mirror or recalculate or iterate the values for  at x-axis (-200,0) and y-axis for (-200,0)
making my new range of x co-ordinates from (-200, 200) and for y  (-200, 200)
how can I have the new values?
The code or mesh is currently like this.

```
xmesh = np.linspace(Xmin, Xmax, 100)
ymesh = np.linspace(Ymin, Ymax, 100)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(xmesh, ymesh)
```

with z being a large array at each mesh grid.